# jQuery infinite scrolling trigger

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that searches the website using jQuery, but am having a problem when a page uses 'infinite scrolling'. Any idea how I could trigger a method when the page is refreshed? Maybe by catching ajax responses?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean catch as in attempt to load the content that is otherwise invisible unless you scroll down, then you could trigger the content to load either by directly calling the function (if it is known and visible in your scope) or you can scroll down and back up once the page is loaded using [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and setting it to the height of the document.